# iOS WeMo SDK Architecture issues

Tags: ios, linker

I'm trying to build an app that controls a WeMo Switch by Belkin. They released their own SDK's to control their product, and I have included them in my Library search paths and in my Linked Libraries and Frame works area.

First I try to compile for all architectures (including arm64) and get the following Mach-O Linker Error

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-
iphoneos/BelkinSDKLibrary.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file
/Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-iphoneos/BelkinSDKLibrary.a (3 slices)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-
iphoneos/WeMoLocalControl.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file 
/Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-iphoneos/WeMoLocalControl.a (3 slices)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-
iphoneos/Cybergarage.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file 
/Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-iphoneos/Cybergarage.a (3 slices)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-
iphoneos/Reachability.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file 
/Users/khwaab/src/enimai/iOS/House Control/-iphoneos/Reachability.a (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_WeMoDiscoveryManager", referenced from:

  objc-class-ref in LightControlViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Next I try to disable arm64 assuming that the libraries are not 64bit (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_xmlGetPredefinedEntity", referenced from:
      _cg_libxml2_get_entity in Cybergarage.a(cxml_parser_libxml2.o)
  "_xmlCreateMemoryParserCtxt", referenced from:
      _cg_libxml2_parsewrapper in Cybergarage.a(cxml_parser_libxml2.o)    
  "_CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      +[NetworkUtilities getCurrentWifiAccessPointName] in           
BelkinSDKLibrary.a(NetworkUtilities.o)
  "_xmlFreeDoc", referenced from:  
      _cg_libxml2_parsewrapper in Cybergarage.a(cxml_parser_libxml2.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
  "_xmlFreeParserCtxt", referenced from:
      _cg_libxml2_parsewrapper in Cybergarage.a(cxml_parser_libxml2.o)
  "_xmlParseDocument", referenced from:
      _cg_libxml2_parsewrapper in Cybergarage.a(cxml_parser_libxml2.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
 "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability description] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability isReachable] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability isConnectionRequired] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability isConnectionOnDemand] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability isInterventionRequired] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      -[Reachability isReachableViaWWAN] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o)
      ...
  "_CNCopySupportedInterfaces", referenced from:
      +[NetworkUtilities getCurrentWifiAccessPointName] in     

BelkinSDKLibrary.a(NetworkUtilities.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.a(Reachability.o) 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

No idea where to go from here, I suspect the library is out of date and not for armv7/7s (it wont build in i386 under the simulator either) but if anyone has had any luck with this or any ideas, anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution that I did to recover from this problem.

- Include the Libraries provided in the folder -iphonesos into your project.
- Add the following frameworks to Project.

  ```
  1. libxml2.dylib
  2. CFNetwork.framework
  3. MobileCoreServices.framework
  4. Security.framework
  5. SystemConfiguration.framework
  ```
- Then go to your build settings & search for architectures.
- Add a new value by clicking other... & add this `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`
- In case you can also choose, `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` means `Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)`
- Build the projects, you will get rid of all the linker errors.

Comment: you saved my career :)

Comment: It's really frustrating, I did the same but it would't work for me. Did any one try building it in xcode9 ?

Answer (score 1):

this is to help even if it is still not working with @Balram's answer .
You have to add -lxml2 in the "other linker flags" properties under Linking section in the build settings of your target.
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]

Using this section to show errors in spite of the armv7 or $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) solution?